# Is the computation of quaternions faster and less prone to rounding errors than the computation of attitude matrices?

Tags: quaternions

I am having trouble understanding this, I hope you guys can help:

Is the computation of quaternions faster and less prone to rounding errors than the computation of attitude matrices, due to the absence of trigonometrical functions (sine, cosine.)? I have been trying to read up on these topics but I could not find a definitive answer.

Comment: It is hard to believe that a few sines and cosines in a $3\times 3$-matrix are the source of rounding errors in the twenty first century. If I am missing something you may want to post a more specific question with more context.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* I think this is a really interesting question! But I also think that [Scientific Computing SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) or even [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) (where there's also a quaternions for attitude control application) are  better sites for it. I'll ping a moderator and suggest it's a candidate for migration there.